# Date Does not accept null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, null

I am creating a gridview that allows the user to enter the date (example Date of Completion) of a specific artifact (There are multiple).  If I try to enter a null or empty value it crashes.  I have looked high and low for an answer to this.  The data they enter is updated to a sql server database.  I have switched the data back and forth between between date and nvarchar.  Also, the value has to bind so it updates the database in the ASP.net.

Code
ASP.NET

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verify Info Prod & Maturity Level" SortExpression="IPMaturity">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IPMaturity") %>' Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Complete" Checked='<%# Bind ("CheckBox1") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblIPMat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IPMaturity") %>' Width="75"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="verticaltext" Height="140px" Width="88px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code C#

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
      DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IPMaturity"));

  if (date1 >= DateTime.Now)
    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

  if (date1 < DateTime.Now)
    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for a nullable DateTime: `DateTime?`

The `System.DateTime` type is a value type so it does not allow null.  The [`Nullable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable?view=net-5.0) class enables setting the value to `null`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
      string ipMaturity = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IPMaturity");
      DateTime? date1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipMaturity) ?  Convert.ToDateTime(ipMaturity) : (DateTime?)null;

  if (date1.HasValue && date1 >= DateTime.Now)
    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

  if (date1.HasValue && date1 < DateTime.Now)
    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
 }
}
```

Now that we are using nullable `DateTime`, the `if` statements are updated to check for `null` to avoid setting the background color until a value is provided.

I am not that familiar with `DataBinder.Eval` so apologies if that does not return a `string`, but hopefully the `DateTime?` will set you in the right direction.

The field in the database will also need to be nullable if you need to save `null` as a value in the database.

Comment: Thank you!  that worked..one minor tweek was I added Convert.ToString to the Databinder...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the necessary items to test it, but I think an `If` statement testing it it's `null` would work.  If that doesn't work, I would use a `try/catch` which I also put below.  If you know the exception being thrown, it'd be nice to catch that.

If Code:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
            {
                DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IPMaturity"));

                if (date1 >= DateTime.Now)
                    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

                if (date1 < DateTime.Now)
                    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }else
            {
                // Data was null, so do something?
            }
        }
    }
```

Try/Catch Code:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IPMaturity"));

                if (date1 >= DateTime.Now)
                    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

                if (date1 < DateTime.Now)
                    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Gracefully handle the exception here
        }
    }
```

Comment: My apologies...this is the exception i get:    System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'